# How to play notification sound on website since google autoplay policy change

Tags: javascript, audio, notifications, autoplay, beep

I've been trying to short beep for a notification on website but google autoplay policy change does not allow me to do so what should I do. I've seen so many sites still doing this like facebook chat etc.

I've tried this with no success (also tried with  element):

```
function beep(vol, freq, duration){
v=a.createOscillator()
u=a.createGain()
v.connect(u)
v.frequency.value=freq
v.type="square"
u.connect(a.destination)
u.gain.value=vol*0.01
v.start(a.currentTime)
v.stop(a.currentTime+duration*0.001);
}
beep(vol, freq, duration);
```

Comment: Is `u` and `v` declared using `var` outside of the function?

Comment: u and v are only inside the function but declared this outside: a=new AudioContext();

Comment: You have to declare variables using `var`. `var a = new Something()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that autoplay sound will be blocked under some circumstance according to the autoplay policy of Chrome.

Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

- User has **interacted** with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user **has previously played** video with sound.
- The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or **installed the PWA** on desktop.
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their **iframes** to allow autoplay with sound.

See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio for more details.

Comment: any idea or example how to do that with your points?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code but `Sound` must be set to `Allow` in Notification settings for that website e.g localhost:8000 in Google Chrome settings

```
 let audio = new Audio("../../assets/sound/quite-impressed.wav");
  audio.play();
```